# How to get special characters out of database with node.js?

Tags: node.js, windows, encoding, utf-8, mariadb

I have a website that is served by a node.js API that gets its data from a mariaDB server.

Now I have that setup on my local machine (windows 7) and an ubuntu server.

When I read Greek characters out of the database and console log them on the server I get the Greek characters, when I do the same on my local machine it does not give me that but Û instead of Omega Ω. This is still on the node.js side the website displays whatever the node.js logs.

Both databases use the same sql file and are utf-8 encoded. And both databases show the Ω correctly when queried directly from the console.

What happens on my local machine? Is it windows? 
If it windows is there something to stop it from doing that?

Comment: How are you viewing the output on Windows?

Comment: @Alastair I have tried the power shell, git bash and webstorm terminal. The power shell shows the omega correctly when querying but not when I use the console log.

Comment: What do you mean "use the console.log" ?

Comment: I have tried running my .js file that outputs the data queried from the database in those consoles to see the console.log/output in them

Comment: Windows console (including Git Bash) does not properly support Unicode. On Windows, it's best to write the output to a text file and read it using Notepad++

Comment: Same result as before it is the Û

Comment: What encoding mode is notepad++ running in?

Comment: It is using UTF-8

Comment: How are you writing to a file?

Comment: Do `SELECT HEX(col)` FROM ...` -- That may give us more clues.

Comment: @Alastair with fs.writeFile

Comment: @Rick  I get a lot of hex values and what to I do with them then?

Comment: @SerenaT - Let me see the hex.  (And indicate what they are supposed to represent.)

Comment: and indicate what connector you use to retrieve data from database. There might be some charset configuration according to this driver